# Looking for connections between Mr. Robot and Fight Club

Tags: reference, fight-club, mr-robot

I noticed that the music playing during the last arcade scene in ep9 of Mr. Robot is a rendition of the song ["Where is my mind" by the Pixies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrdpliMfoAM), which is the closing music for Fight Club.

> The other obvious connection is the fact about a character in another character's head.

Did anybody notice any other references to the movie?

Comment: Related: http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/37230/49

Comment: Please don't put the *entire* question into spoiler markup, though. The question itself should still make significant sense without the spoiler markup. There is absolutely no problem with spoilers in the question body, as explained in the [help center](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). For more information, you can also take a look at the relevant meta discussions: http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/16/49 and http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/82/49.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there are connections with fight club for Tone and camera movement (as explained in [this article](http://www.vulture.com/2015/07/mr-robot-influences-taxi-driver-girls.html?mid=facebook_vulture)) and also the very basic concept of talking to himself.

There are also connections with other movies as you can see in the link.

Also according to [this article](http://zap2it.com/2015/09/classic-films-that-influenced-mr-robot/):

> In the film, Edward Norton’s narrator tells us an entire story — then proves to be unreliable because of mental illness. In “Mr. Robot” … well, no spoilers here, but you get the point. Both are brilliantly-created pieces of pop culture that serve to entertain, thrill and disturb. And both seem to ultimately have a similar message: Sometimes, it seems, your worst enemy can be your own mind.

Comment: Huh! _"Your worst enemy can be your own mind"_. Tell that to [**Billy Milligan**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billy_Milligan#Personalities).

Answer (score 1):

The movie Fight Club has been cited as an inspiration for Mr. Robot's plot. 
The whole dissociative identity disorder, clearing the world of debt were the prime points that the series takes from Mr. Robot.

"Where's my mind" was also added as a tribute to Fight Club in the sound track.

However, using the key plot points from Fight Club, director Sam Esmail built the series by using a lot of techniques and elements from various other movies and series from the past.

For more: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr.*Robot*(TV_series)#/Influences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Robot_(TV_series)#/Influences)

Answer (score 1):

Elliot's whole f*%k society rant in the first episode could be considered a more violent and direct version of Tyler Durden's single serving friends monologue - [Single serving friends speech from Fight Club (movie)](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DfV8HnQq5frQ&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjit4GuxLjaAhXn5YMKHVuBBDAQtwIIGDAB&usg=AOvVaw3QJBaMLxjO25J8ouchVLuV)